# cxf-codegen-plugin does not comply with cxf ValidationFeature

Tags: java, web-services, validation, cxf

According to [ValidationFeature documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/ValidationFeature) in order for the validation to happen the operations input and output bindings must be annotated with `@Valid`

However, the webservice interface generated by cxf-codegen-plugin does not have these annotations, and I don't seem to find a command line argument or a plugin that allows to add them.

The `@Valid` annotations cannot be put in the implementation of the webservice interface without violating Liskov substitution principle: the reference implementation of JSR-349 (Hibernate Validator) in this case produces *HV000151: A method overriding another method must not alter the parameter constraint configuration*

**Question:** Is anybody aware of a way to annotate the cxf-generated webservice interface method parameters with `@Valid`?

I'm aware of the existance of the [Annox plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) but this does not seems to be an easy task to accomplish with it. 
The easiest solution possible would be to manually add the `@Valid` annotation to the webservice interface but I'm not comfortable in modifying generated code

**Example**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example.www</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice-test-bval</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Test bean validation on web service</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.boot.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot.version>
        <com.github.krasa.krasa-jaxb-tools>1.5</com.github.krasa.krasa-jaxb-tools>
        <org.apache.cxf.version>3.1.3</org.apache.cxf.version>
        <cxf-codegen-plugin.version>3.0.1</cxf-codegen-plugin.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- CXF dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Schema validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
            <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${com.github.krasa.krasa-jaxb-tools}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-XJsr303Annotations</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
                        <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>${com.github.krasa.krasa-jaxb-tools}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*src/main/resources/wsdl/*

test.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    name="test" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">
            <xsd:element name="NewOperation">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="in">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="10" />
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="20" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="NewOperationResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="out">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]+" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="NewOperationRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:NewOperation" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="NewOperationResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:NewOperationResponse" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="testWS">
        <jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
            <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
        </jaxws:bindings>
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:NewOperationRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:NewOperationResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="testWSSOAP" type="tns:testWS">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/test/NewOperation" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="testWS">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:testWSSOAP" name="testWSSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

*src/main/java/*

org.example.test

```
package org.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

package org.example.test;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

import org.example.test.ObjectFactory;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/test/", name = "testWS")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TestWSValid {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "NewOperation", action = "http://www.example.org/test/NewOperation")
    @Valid @WebResult(name = "NewOperationResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/test/", partName = "parameters")
    public NewOperationResponse newOperation(
            @Valid @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "NewOperation", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/test/")
        NewOperation parameters
    );
}
```

org.example.test.configuration

```
package org.example.test.configuration;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationFeature;
import org.example.test.services.TestWSImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml", "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.example.test" })
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Bus cxfBus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint testWSEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new TestWSImpl());
        endpoint.setAddress("/testws");
        endpoint.publish();
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public Feature validationFeature() {
        Feature validationFeature = new BeanValidationFeature();
        validationFeature.initialize(cxfBus);
        cxfBus.getFeatures().add(validationFeature);
        ConstraintViolationInterceptor interceptor = new ConstraintViolationInterceptor();
        cxfBus.getInFaultInterceptors().add(interceptor);
        cxfBus.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(interceptor);
        cxfBus.getProperties().put("exceptionMessageCauseEnabled", true);
        return validationFeature;
    }
}

package org.example.test.configuration;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

public class ConstraintViolationInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public ConstraintViolationInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
        getBefore().add(Soap11FaultOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    private static final String TEMPLATE = "[{0}] {1} : {2}";

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        Fault fault = (Fault) message.getContent(Exception.class);
        Throwable exception = fault.getCause();
        if (exception instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            fault.setMessage(processConstraints((ConstraintViolationException) exception));
        }
    }

    private String processConstraints(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return exception.getConstraintViolations().stream().map((error) -> {
            return MessageFormat.format(TEMPLATE, error.getPropertyPath(), error.getMessage(), error.getInvalidValue());
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }

}
```

org.example.test.services

```
package org.example.test.services;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.example.test.NewOperation;
import org.example.test.NewOperationResponse;
import org.example.test.ObjectFactory;
import org.example.test.TestWS;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.example.test.TestWS", portName = "TestWSPort", serviceName = "TestWS", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/test/")
public class TestWSImpl implements TestWS {

    @Override
    public NewOperationResponse newOperation(NewOperation parameters) {
        int in = parameters.getIn();
        NewOperationResponse response = new ObjectFactory().createNewOperationResponse();
        if (in < 10 || in > 20) {
            response.setOut("no no no");
        } else {
            response.setOut("OK");
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

With reference to the project above, you can test that as long as `TestWSImpl implements TestWS` (the generated class) there is no validation occurring, but if `TestWSImpl implements TestWSValid` (the class that contains the generated code with the `@Valid` addition) then the validation works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache CXF's wsdl2java support is pluggable. There is a META-INF/tools-plugin.xml descriptor that allows you to define custom generators ("frontend profiles"). So if you need a `@Valid` annotation on all cxf-generated webservice interfaces, you can just plug-in a custom `SEIGenerator`.
Apache CXF uses Velocity templates to generate the SEI interfaces. So you just need to overwrite the default template with the custom one.

So instead of using the Anox or Krasa you can just create a simple `cxf-codegen-plugin` overwrite.

So lets create a separate project, still you can put it in the same project but in different module, but for better reusability I would say a new project.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>org.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>valid-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Lets use service loader to define new default SEI generator.

**src/main/resources/META-INF/tools-plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/tools/plugin" name="play" version="" provider="play.typesafe.com">
    <frontend name="sample" package="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws" profile="JAXWSProfile">
    <container name="JAXWSContainer" package="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws" toolspec="jaxws-toolspec.xml"/>
    <processor name="WSDLToJavaProcessor" package="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor"/>
    <builder name="JAXWSDefinitionBuilder" package="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11"/>
    <generators package="com.example.plugin">
        <generator name="CustomSEIGenerator"/>
    </generators>
</frontend>
```

Here we have defined a new `SEIGenerator` with name `CustomSEIGenerator` from the package `com.example.plugin`

Next lets define a velocity template with all of our overwrites (in our case just hardcoded `@Valid` annotation on web service interface) This one is based on the official CXF [`sei.vm`](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/tools/wsdlto/frontend/jaxws/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/frontend/jaxws/template/sei.vm)

**src/main/resources/valid-sei.vm**

```
#if ($intf.packageJavaDoc != "")
/**
$intf.packageJavaDoc
 */
#end
package $intf.PackageName;

#if ($mark-generated == "true")
import javax.annotation.Generated;
#end
import javax.validation.Valid;
#foreach ($import in $intf.Imports)
import ${import};
#end

/**
#if ($intf.classJavaDoc != "")
 $intf.classJavaDoc
 *
 #end
 * This class was generated by $fullversion
 * $currentdate
 * Generated source version: $version
 * 
 */
#foreach ($annotation in $intf.Annotations)
 $annotation
#end
#if ($mark-generated == "true")
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date =     "$currentdate", comments = "$fullversion")
#end
public interface $intf.Name ${sei-superinterface-string}{
#foreach ($method in $intf.Methods)

#if ($method.JavaDoc != "")
    /**
${method.JavaDoc}
     */
#end
#foreach ($annotation in $method.Annotations)
    $annotation
#end
@Valid
#if ($mark-generated == "true")
    @Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "$currentdate")
#end
    public $method.returnValue ${method.Name}(#if($method.ParameterList.size() == 0))#end
#if($method.ParameterList.size() != 0)

#foreach ($param in ${method.ParameterList})
    $param
#end
)#end#if($method.Exceptions.size() > 0) throws#foreach($exception in $method.Exceptions) $exception.ClassName#if($method.Exceptions.size() != $velocityCount),#end#end#end;
#end
}
```

And at the end lets create the `CustomSEIGenerator` which will use our velocity template.

```
package org.example.test;

import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.SEIGenerator;

import java.io.Writer;

/**
 * Just a sample custom generator which use custom velocity template to generate SEI
 *
 */
public class CustomSEIGenerator extends SEIGenerator {

    @Override
    protected void doWrite(String templateName, Writer outputs) throws ToolException {

        if (templateName.endsWith("/sei.vm")) {
            templateName = "valid-sei.vm";
        }

        super.doWrite(templateName, outputs);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have build the plugin overwrite and published to your local maven repo, next you just need to add a dependency information to your project `pom.xml`.
So the pom from the question will remain the same only the `cxf-codegen-plugin` will get a new dependency.

**In your pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            </wsdlOption>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>sample</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.example.test</groupId>                      
                <artifactId>valid-cxf</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Thats it, now you can fully manage what and how is generated from your wsdl.

A fully working example can be found at this repo https://github.com/babltiga/cxf-valid-sample

Comment: I fixed the missing tag in the given tools-plugin.xml and I indeed built and configured the custom generator plugin as a dependency as you described, but I still don't see the @Valid annotation. What do you think that I may be missing?

Comment: Basically my example was just missing the front end name parameter which  needs to be  passed to cxf generator via adding `<extraarg>-fe</extraarg><extraarg>sample</extraarg>`. Just see updated pom.xml.

Comment: great, indeed it is working now! Thanks for putting it all toghether I was too lazy not to do it myself. I have just a remark: it is not convenient to override the template, because this would get difficult to maintain. I found it better to override SEIGenerator.generate(ToolContext) and make the modification in the model

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is what I think it's best for CustomSEIGenerator implementation:

```
package org.example.test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.cxf.helpers.CastUtils;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolContext;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JAnnotation;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaInterface;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaMethod;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaModel;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.common.model.JavaParameter;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.SEIGenerator;
import org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.processor.WSDLToJavaProcessor;

public class CustomSEIGenerator extends SEIGenerator {

  private static final String VALID_PARAM  = "VALID_PARAM";

  private static final String VALID_RETURN = "VALID_RETURN";

  @Override
  public void generate(ToolContext penv) throws ToolException {
    JAnnotation validAnno = new JAnnotation(Valid.class);
    Map<QName, JavaModel> map = CastUtils.cast((Map<?, ?>) penv.get(WSDLToJavaProcessor.MODEL_MAP));
    for (JavaModel javaModel : map.values()) {
      Map<String, JavaInterface> interfaces = javaModel.getInterfaces();

      for (JavaInterface intf : interfaces.values()) {
        intf.addImport(Valid.class.getCanonicalName());
        List<JavaMethod> methods = intf.getMethods();

        for (JavaMethod method : methods) {
          List<JavaParameter> parameters = method.getParameters();
          method.addAnnotation(VALID_RETURN, validAnno);
          for (JavaParameter param : parameters) {
            param.addAnnotation(VALID_PARAM, validAnno);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    super.generate(penv);
  }
}
```